# Array.isArray: Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this piece of code:

```
 const bookingValue: string | string[] | undefined = headers[header];
        if (Array.isArray(bookingValue)) {
```

but I have this compilation error on `Array.isArray`:

Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative

Comment: Its simple enough to create your own, (typeof bookingValue == "object" && typeof bookingValue.length == "number")

Comment: Please check your import, from where is imported isArray method.

Comment: Can you share minimal reproducible code snippet on TypeScript Playground and share us the link?

Comment: [It is not depcrecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)